# Displaying value and option in CodeIgniter using form dropdown

Tags: codeigniter

How to display id and option value separately using form dropdown in CodeIgniter? Data id and value will be retrieved from database. I must use form dropdown function.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this URL

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

from your controller, built the sql statement to retrieve the id,name from database and send it in a array format to the view..

For ex.

in your controller,

```
$data['category_list']=array('1'=>'1st category',2=>'2nd category'.. etc);
```

in your view,

```
<div> Select category </div>
<div><?php echo form_dropdown("category",$category_list)?>
```

// here $category_list which is derived from the Controller.